# Has anyone out there succeeded in building Chrome under Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I am quantitatively studying various metrics associated with automated tests. Chrome seems to have a reasonable set, so I wanted to add it to my data set. I downloaded the Chrome source code and tried to build it with VisualStudio but got several hundred errors--types not defined, identifiers not defined, etc. Has anyone out there succeeded in building Chrome under Windows? Are there tricks I need to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Chromium dev page:

## Compilation failures

Some common things to think about when you have weird compilation failures:

- Make sure you have SP1 for Visual Studio 2005. It's required. Really.
- Sometimes Visual Studio does the wrong thing when building Chromium and gets stuck on a bogus error. A good indication of this is if it is only failing for one person but others (including the Buildbots) are not complaining. To resolve this, try the following steps:

  - Close Visual Studio.
  - Sync to the tip of tree and ensure there are no conflicts ("svn st" should not show any "C"s in front of files that you've changed).
  - If there were conflicts, sync again after resolving them.
  - Manually erase the output directory (chrome\Debug and chrome\Release. Using the command line, you can use "erase /S /Q Debug Release" from the chrome directory to do this, or "rm -rf Debug Release" if you have Unix-like tools installed.
  - Restart Visual Studio and open the Chromium solution.
  - Rebuild the solution.

If it still doesn't work, repeating this process probably won't help.

## chrome_kjs.sln tempfile problems

If, while building JavaScriptCore, you see errors like:

```
3>Error in tempfile() using /tmp/dftables-XXXXXXXX.in: Parent directory (/tmp/) is not writable
3> at /cygdrive/c/b/slave/WEBKIT~1/build/webkit/third_party/JavaScriptCore/pcre/dftables line 236
3>make: *** [chartables.c] Error 255
```

...it's because the Cygwin installation included in the Chromium source is having trouble mapping the NT ACL to POSIX permissions. This seems to happen when Chromium is checked out into a directory for which Cygwin can't figure out the permissions in the first place, possibly when the directory is created from within a Cygwin environment before running mkpasswd. Cygwin then imposes its own access control, which is incorrectly restrictive. As a workaround, do one of the following:

- Edit the NT permissions on third_party\cygwin\tmp to allow Modify and Write actions for Everyone and machine\Users. Cygwin is able to figure this out. Or,
- Figure out what went wrong with your checkout and try again - try doing the checkout from cmd instead of from a Cygwin shell, then verify that the permissions aren't completely blank in your Cygwin installation. Or,
- Bypass Cygwin's access control (NT's will still be in effect) by editing webkit\build\JavaScriptCore\prebuild.bat and webkit\build\WebCore\prebuild.bat to include the following line before invoking anything that uses Cygwin:

  ```
       set CYGWIN=nontsec
  ```

Only one of these solutions should be needed.